# How to change target .NET framework used in Unity 2019+

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I need to change my target framework in an unity project, since I get the following error when using a custom built namespace.

> The primary reference "CUSTOM" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1".

Answer (score 0):

in project settings>player>other settings>configuration>  theres an option for api compatibility level.

Comment: That only lets you select .NET4x not the exact version